# What is keras.backend.tf?

Tags: keras

I found some code using keras.backend.tf. But I couldn't find any information about this library.I wonder if keras.backend.tf equals to tensorflow,so that I could use any function in tf by keras.backend.tf. For example,I can use keras.backend.tf.argmax just like tf.argmx.

```py
from keras.engine import Layer
import keras.backend as K
    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        padding = self.padding
        pool_size = self.pool_size
        strides = self.strides
        if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
            ksize = [1, pool_size[0], pool_size[1], 1]
            padding = padding.upper()
            strides = [1, strides[0], strides[1], 1]
            output, argmax = K.tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(
                inputs,
                ksize=ksize,
                strides=strides,
                padding=padding)
        else:
            errmsg = '{} backend is not supported for layer {}'.format(
                K.backend(), type(self).__name__)
            raise NotImplementedError(errmsg)
        argmax = K.cast(argmax, K.floatx())
        return [output, argmax]
```

Comment: The true is that Keras library is using Tensorflow like backend

Comment: Does that mean I can use take keras.backend.tf as tf? I mean  if I use  "import keras.backend.tf as tf", I can consider it as  "import tensorflow as tf" ?

Comment: import tensorflow as tf is ok

Comment: I don't think you can use `keras.backend.tf` synonymously as `tensorflow`

Comment: Yes, I can not use 'import keras.backend.tf'. It will give the message 'No module named 'keras.backend.tf'. However, I can directly use keras.backend.tf as tensorflow from several experiments I made.So I guess keras.backend.tf equals to tensorflow in some sense. Is it right?